# How to make a dynamic SQL insert via xhr?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, postgresql, xmlhttprequest

I'm loading my DB to tables and my idea was to enable dynamic edit on the fly, like it is in phpMyAdmin. It wasn't that hard. From the front-end side, at least. Creating remove function for records was also easy, but I can't come with any idea how to make a dynamic insert. Particularly, how to phrase a query that would access the values from the newly edited table row which is meant to be a new record.

As for removing records I use:

```
var xhr;
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
  if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
  }
}

$.fn.delClick = function() {

  var table = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  var row = $(this).parent()

  if(confirm("Are you sure?"))
  {

    var tableName = table.find('.add').data('tablename');
    var idName = table.find('.add').data('idname');
    var rowId = row.children('td.id').html();

    xhr.open("POST","scripts/delete?tableName="+tableName+"&idName="+idName+"&rowId="+rowId,true);
    xhr.send(); 

    row.remove();


  }
}
```

and in `scripts/delete.php` :

```
$this->ci =& get_instance(); 

$remove = $this->ci->db->query("DELETE FROM ".$_GET['tableName']." WHERE ".$_GET['idName']." = '".$_GET['rowId']."'");
```

I hope to make something similar about inserting records, but I'm stuck.
The main problem with inserting records is that I can't pass variables via `POST`, because amount of columns vary for each table, so that the amount of variables I would need to pass to my `scripts/insert.php` would also vary. Or maybe there is a way?

Comment: You should be doing security checks, your script in its current form is a disaster. Anyway as for the dynamic fields you can use .serialize() in javascript which would take the fields & prepare them to be sent through ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use object

```
var inputs = {};
$('.formInput').each(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
    inputs[id] = val ;
});

$.post( insert_url , {inputs:inputs});
```

also you can analyze some simpler crud systems like

```
https://github.com/maxxxir/mz-codeigniter-crud
```